# Not seeing much an improvement to x265 encoding after libmfx rebuild for ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, performance, encoding, rebuild

OK I guess I am just asking if this is normal or not.

I have rebuilt my ffmpeg to use the libmfx/HDi driver. I have seen a significant improvement in the x264 encoding, around 4.5 time faster from my initial tests.

Speed standard ffmpeg : 8.43x
Speed rebuilt ffmpeg  : 39.9x

But i'm not seeing much difference on x265:

Speed standard ffmpeg : 8.52x
Speed rebuilt ffmpeg  : 9.01x

I have an intel i3-7100t processor. I am aware it doesn't do 10bit (quick sync) encoding, so I am using the switch [-pix_fmt yuv420p] to ensure it's doing 8bit.

The full command I am using is:

> ffmpeg  -init_hw_device vaapi=va:/dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device va -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -i bbb-short.avi -c:v libx265 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -crf 21 OUTPUT265x.mp4

Am I missing something here, or is this just what to expect from x265/ffmpeg/This processor?

Extra info: I'm running ubuntu 20.04, fully patched etc. intel i3-7100t, 16gb of ram, the intel HDi media driver (not the free one that doesn't for x265), I installed all the libmfx stuff (at least I hope I did). Latest version of each one, i.e. I did the build within the last 48 hours.

Admittedly I only tested on one video clip, which was raw (not compressed). But I just want to see what others had experienced.  Let me know if I have missed any key info.

Thanks

Comment: What's your command for the x264 encoding?

Comment: ffmpeg -init_hw_device vaapi=va:/dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device va -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -i bbb-short.avi -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 21 OUTPUT264x.mp4

Comment: Pretty much the same as x265, but with the 8K bit removed, and obviously 264 instead of 265.